# Как вычислить модуль комплексного числа и найти комплексное число, обратное заданному?

Tags: java

*Нужно создать комплексное число: действительная(а1) и мнимая(b1)(класс родитель и его поля). Вычислить модуль комплексного числа(метод1) и найти комплексное число, обратное заданному(метод2)*

Нужна помощь, никак дальше сообразить не могу. Помогите дописать 2 метода

```
public class Complex {

    private final double a1;   // the real part    
    private final double b1;   // the imaginary part

    // create a new object with the given real and imaginary parts
    public Complex(double real, double imag) {
        a1 = real;
        b1 = imag;
    }

    public Complex modul(Complex b, Complex a) {
       метод нахождения модуля комплексного числа
        double real = ?
       // double imag = ?
        return new Complex(real, imag);
    }

       public Complex returnchisl(Complex b, Complex a) {

       метод нахождения числа, обратное заданному 

    }
}
```

Comment: Сначала прочитайте теорию по комплексным числам. То что вы тут написали - полный бред. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/complex.html комплексные числа реализованы в уйме библиотек, в том числе и на java

Comment: модуль комплексного числа - скаляр, считается по теореме пифагора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Определим класс комплексного числа:

```
public class Complex {
    private double mRe;
    private double mIm;

    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        mRe = re;
        mIm = im;
    }

    public double getRe() {
        return mRe;
    }

    public double getIm() {
        return mIm;
    }
}
```

Здесь все просто: класс с двумя полями, соответствующими действительной и мнимой частям комплексного числа; конструктор и два геттера.

Модуль комплексного числа `z=x+i*y` определяется выражением `|z| = sqrt(x^2+y^2)`. Добавим в приведенный выше класс метод, возвращающий модуль данного комплексного числа:

```
public class Complex {
    private double mRe;
    private double mIm;

    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        mRe = re;
        mIm = im;
    }

    public double getRe() {
        return mRe;
    }

    public double getIm() {
        return mIm;
    }

    public double abs() {
        return Math.sqrt(mRe*mRe + mIm*mIm);
    }
}
```

Для комплексного числа `z = x+i*y` обратное ему будет иметь вид: `1/z = x/(x^2+y^2) - i*y/(x^2+y^2)`. Реализуем соответствующий метод:

```
public class Complex {
    private double mRe;
    private double mIm;

    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        mRe = re;
        mIm = im;
    }

    public double getRe() {
        return mRe;
    }

    public double getIm() {
        return mIm;
    }

    public double abs() {
        return Math.sqrt(mRe*mRe + mIm*mIm);
    }

    public Complex getReciprocal() {
        double denominator = mRe*mRe + mIm*mIm;
        if (denominator != 0) {
            return new Complex(mRe/denominator, -mIm/denominator);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("z = 0");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Re = " + mRe + ", Im = " + mIm;
    }
}
```

Здесь еще переопределен метод `toString()` для получения текстового представления комплексного числа.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, особенно за каждое пояснение :)